# What is the fastest way to get modification date of a list of files in a directory using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have a folder in a directory with a large amount of csv files (500+). I only need the csv files with a modification date after a certain date. Eventually I will pd.concat these files into a single pandas dataframe.

What is the fastest way to get an overview of the relevant files?

My current solution looks like this:

```
## get list of files
list_of_files = glob.glob(Path + '*.csv')

## transform to datataframe
df_files = pd.DataFrame(list_of_files, columns = ['files'])

## Calculate modification time (SLOW)
df_files['Modification_Time'] = df_files['files'].apply(lambda x: datetime.date.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(x)))

## Eventually filter based on Modification date and pd.concat relevant files (code not relevant for the question)
```

My solution is rather slow and I was wondering if there is a faster solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the other answers address your root problem here - sure avoiding loading the dataframes is sensible, but it isn't speeding up your getmtime call.

Under the hood you are actually making multiple calls on the file table, when you can make a single call.  Instead of using `glob`, use `os.scandir` (python 3.5+) which will allow you to list all the files in a directory AND see the modified time in a single call.  On Windows this is almost 10x faster, since Windows filesystem automatically responds with the modified time - glob is just not exposing it to you.  On *nix the speed up is smaller (2x? - see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/)

So you want something like

```
import os

scan_of_files = os.scandir(Path)
name_with_times = {f.name : datetime.fromtimestamp(f.stat().st_mtime) 
                           for f in scan_of_files if f.name[-4:] == ".csv"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to evaluate the modification time before initializing dataframe -

```
import glob

result=  []
for file in glob.glob(Path + '*.csv'):
    temp = {
        'files': file,
        'Modification_Time': datetime.date.fromtimestamp(
            os.path.getmtime(file)
        ),
    }
    result.append(temp)
    
df_files = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Identify the files you want before loading them:

```py
from datetime import datetime

# Find files that were modified after 7PM on 2021-04-30
mtime = datetime(2021, 4, 30, 19, 0, 0).timestamp()

list_of_files = [
    file for file in glob.glob(path + '*.csv')
        if os.path.getmtime(file) > mtime
]
```